# Fix position images in a responsive website

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design

I have a WordPress website which has 2 icons in its homepage but if you resize the browser the icon moves. How do I set their position to be fixed?

Tried: `position:fixed` (item disappears) `position:absolute` (won`t help)
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Post any relevant code please.

Comment: Used this css for the icons in my homepage you can see the visual composer in this print screen along with the code.Check Latest

Comment: `pic.icon-globe:before {
content: "\f0ac";
margin-left: 209px;
margin-top: 20px;
width: 20px;
}
.icon-group:before {
content: "\f0c0";
margin-left: 206px;
margin-top: 22px;
}`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why do you need margins in :before element, should be straightforward without them, Is there any chance to see the website live? This would ease the help.

---

I would give the parent element (the numbers) css: position: relative  and than the :before elements : position: absolute  left - 20px or something.

Comment: Used that margins to set the position of the elements because they were placed automatically in the left of the page. I will be kind of tricky to give someone access because the website is under maintenance an you will need an account to access it.

Comment: I would give the parent element (the numbers) css: position: relative and than the :before elements : position: absolute left - 20px or something.

Comment: this should do, if You understand what I mean